# Cyclic Permutations and Transposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, notation

I'm new to Group Theory and I'm studying on my own.

I found the following from the book by Michael Artin.

If $S_3$ is a symmetric group it has order 3!=6.
It says to describe $S_3$, we can pick two permutations in terms of which we can write all others.
And then it goes ahead picks up a cyclic permutation {1,2,3} and the transposition {1,2} and label them as x and y respectively.

The rules $x^3=1,y^2=1,yx=x^2y$ can be verified.

What are cyclic permutations and transpositions?
And how do I verify these rules?

and then it says that using the cancellation law we can prove that $1,x,x^2,y,xy,x^2y$ are distinct. How can I show this using cancellation law? and why is $y^2$ not included in this?

Comment: You're asking for definitions for a **cyclic permutation** and a **transposition**. I imagine that this is defined in Artin book. If not, looking at wikipedia will provide you with immediate definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Transposition exchanges two elements of a permutation such as $y = (1,2)$, mapping 1 to 2 and 2 to 1. It is then clear that $y^2 = 1$ (identity).

$x=(1,2,3)$ is a cyclic permutation, mapping 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and 3 to 1. It is clear that $x^2=(1,3,2)$ and $x^3=1$ (identity).

Now calculate $xy$ and $x^2y$ which are both transitions.

Comment: Should I delete this question?...It seems like a stupid question to ask!

Comment: Not at all.  I just added a tag to make it clearer where the problem was.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobertShore....as I said m new to the this whole concept on group theory....and when I say x and y being asked to multiply I thought it was asking to multiply elements with each other...never thought it was looking for a composition of functions

Comment: .......thanks a lot @Wuestenfex